# Нет ссылки на mysql в Xamarin

Tags: c#, mysql, xamarin

По немому [видеоуроку](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jfZUXfb05uk&ab_channel=ProgrammingwithSinghateh) разобрался как подключатся к базе даннных mysql, сделал для теста такой же проект как на видео, для windows, через пкм по "ссылка" подключил MySql.Data. проверил, всё работает. радостный побежал в свой проект не под windows form, а в проект Xamarin и очень быстро обломался т.к. ссылки на MySql.Data просто нет
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Пробовал даже заходить в "управление пакетами NuGet" и ставить MySql.Data, установка прошла успешно, появился среди ссылок MySql.Data в древе, однако в поиске ссылок его по прежнему нет и using MySql.Data.MySqlClient; выдаёт ошибку MySql
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Мне кажется у вас проблема в том что вы учились по видео уроку вместо документации и книг, но может только кажется :)

Comment: Мне нужно это для Дипломной работы, поэтому я использую все доступные варианты т.к. мне лишь бы сделать. У меня нет ни желания, ни времени читать 500 страниц литературы, чтобы разобраться как подключить mysal. Факт в том что в один из моих проектов, windows form подключается misql и я даже смог подключится к бд и выдать в форму даные из бд. в xamarin - не выходит

Comment: Хей, у меня вышло, я через NuGet установил mysql, но не для ANDROID или IOS, а для самого проекта,в моей случае HelpMT

Comment: Не тем вы занимаетесь. В C# есть отличный инструмент для баз данных, зовется `EntityFramework`, вот его ставьте и радуйтесь

Comment: @EvgeniyZ
Интересно, посмотрю. Мне главное чтобы база была не локальная и чтобы оно работало с мобильным приложением